# Como guardar un PDF desde Firebase en las descargas del teléfono?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Como puedo hacer para descargar un **PDF** que tengo en **Firebase** y guardarlo en "Descargas"?. Hasta el momento solo he podido guardarlo en Cache pero esa no es mi intención ya que necesito que el usuario tenga el archivo físico en su teléfono para abrirlo luego si desea.

**Método que utilizo para descargar el PDF por el momento:**

```
public void Downloadfile(String url){
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference pathReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

    try {
        File file = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        localFile = File.createTempFile("Imagen","jpg");
        //File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Trabajo.pdf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"PDF guardado en: "+localFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Error al descargar el PDF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

En el método, recibo como parámetro la `key` del **PDF** para luego descargarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que te lo guarda en cache es por esta linea

```
localFile = File.createTempFile("Imagen","jpg");
```

y si estas bajando un pdf no deberias guardarlo como `jpg`

para resolverlo intenta lo siguiente

```
File rootPath = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File pdfFile = new File(rootPath, "Trabajo.pdf");

pathReference.getFile(pdfFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"PDF guardado en: "+pdfFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Error al descargar el PDF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```